# Does Peter Parker ever cry in the comics, or the animated series?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man

After one of my friends said Peter Parker cries too much in the first movie trilogy, and I said that it was because he saw some relatives dying, he challenged me to find any example of him crying in the comics.

I didn't read the comics, I only saw the famous animated series on television.

Does he cry at any point in the comics? Or in the animated series?

Comment: "Any moment" sounds like a 'list question'...I assume you don't mean ALL which would be too broad. Surely one or two examples are enough?

Comment: Yes he did; over his Aunt May, I forget the plotline though.

Comment: My gut reaction is 'Peter Parker cries frequently' - he's a teenager who has to deal with school, and work and being a hero, and guilt from his Uncle, and protecting his loved ones, and protecting a city. A huge part of his story is always how he deals with that and often he can't deal.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, Peter Parker is shown (multiple times) crying over the death of Uncle Ben.

In fact, the very first time we see his famous line about great power and great responsibility, it's in a scene where Peter is crying (in *Amazing Fantasy #15*, the very first Spider-Man story before he even had his own solo comic):

[image]

He also famously cries just before his own death in the Ultimate universe storyline "The Death of Spider-Man":

[image]

Comment: Yay thanks, already two things to show to him ! So this is a very old and a very recent ones. Both after death of Uncle Ben. So I supposed there is other version of Peter Parker crying after his Uncle death...But is there other moment ?

Comment: I would assume there's probably other moments, I just don't know any off hand. Also, note that these are two different versions of Spider-Man (the original and the Ultimates one).

Comment: Who's the white-haired person in the second comic?

Comment: It's Aunt May, and the person who's silhouette you see is MJ.

Comment: Calling *Amazing Fantasy #15* an "early" story is an understatement... it's the *first* Spider-Man story ever published.

Answer (score 11):

As for the animated series, in the most recent one, Ultimate Spider-Man, here's a small clip of Parker crying after he was betrayed and had his identity revealed to Doc Ock:

Here's a screenshot of the moment:

[image]

And here's one from the 90s Spidey series of Parker crying after he sees Uncle Ben:

[image]

Comment: Is there a moment in the 90s series where the "main" Peter Parker cries (and not a version from a different reality)?

Comment: To my knowledge and memory, no.  The moment I thought he might have cried was when clone MJ evaporated, but he was masked entire time and more angry than anything.

Answer (score 3):

I remember in the death of Captain America story arc he cries over Steve's death as well as Uncle Ben's and is consoled by Wolverine

Comment: Some images of the this (I assume its a comic strip) could greatly improve this answer.